# PhP call a function and pass parameters to construct

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have a class social which has:

```
protected $id;

public function __construct($request, $id)
{
    Log::info('Processing...', ['request' => $request, 'id' => $id]);
    try {
        $client = new Client();
        $url =  sprintf($request);
        $response = $client->get($url);
        $json = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
        return $json;
    } catch (ClientException $exception) {
        $responseBody = $exception->getResponse()->getBody(true);
        Log::error($responseBody, ['entity_id' => $id]);
    }
}
public function wikipedia($wikipedia_url, $id)
{
  dd($json);
    try {
        $wikipedia_array = $json['parse']['text'];
        $wikipedia_array = array_slice($wikipedia_array, 0, 9);
        $wikipedia_array = implode($wikipedia_array, ',');
        Log::info('Processed Wikipedia for', ['entity_id' => $id]);
        return $wikipedia_array;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error('Wikipedia:', ['message' => $e->getMessage(), 'entity_id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

In another function I am calling a facade like this:

```
    $id = $entity->id;
    $wikipedia_id = $entity->wikipedia;
    if (!empty($wikipedia_id)) {
        $wikipedia_url =  'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&prop=text&section=0&disablelimitreport=1&format=json&page='.$wikipedia_id;
        $wikipedia_html = Social::wikipedia($wikipedia_url, $id);
        Log::info('Wikipedia ok for', ['entity_id' => $id]);
    }
```

However I get this:

> Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Helpers\Social::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/vagrant/liveandnow/app/Providers/SocialServiceProvider.php on line 35 and exactly 2 expected

Can anyone explain to me how to call a method, pass parameters to it but also pass them along to construct?

Here's my facade:

```
<?php

namespace App\Facade;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class Social extends Facade
{
    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'social';
    }
}
```

and service provider:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('social', function ($app) {
        return new Social;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the error lies in the service provider.
You define a constructor with 2 parameters,

`public function __construct($request, $id)`

but in your service provider you call it like this:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('social', function ($app) {
        return new Social;
    });
}
```

You need to add both arguments when instantiating the Social class, for example like

`return new Social("http://xyz.de", 1);`

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for that info, makes sense however how do I pass them 'dynamically' because in your example you are of course hard coding them but I need to pass them as $url, $id for example